# Mavericks: createinstallmedia not found

Tags: macos, usb, install, startup

I'm having trouble with this. It seems the standard way is to have the OS X install file in your Applications folder and then run the following in Terminal

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app --nointeraction
```

But when I do that, all I get is the error

> command not found

I can't see how it could be the file path because this is the line of text given in various online tutorials for people to copy and paste?

On a different note, I then tried to create a bootable USB the more 'old school' way purely through Disk Utility, but then found that my USB drive doesn't show up when I hold down the Option key when booting up my Mac... all I see is 'Macintosh HD' or 'Recovery HD' (or whatever they're called).

Might that be related to my problem?

Comment: I assume you downloaded Mavericks from the App Store and the downloaded app can be found in the Applications folder? If you have, then use the Finder application to see if the command `createinstallmedia` exists in the folder `/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources`.

Comment: thanks but I've managed to fix it now, had to run another command in Terminal (see my answer posted)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix it by running the following command:

```
sudo chmod +x /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia
```